# Can we use BLPAPI remotely?

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

The SDKs at https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/ allow you to connect to localhost 8194 to fetch data. Please correct if any of the following is incorrect:
The use of the SDK requires the installation of a Terminal software on the PC where the program using the SDK is being run.
The Terminal software creates an endpoint listening on port 8194 through which the data can be fetched.

Question:
Is it possible for another computer in the local network to run the SDK and connect to the computer that hosts the Terminal service?

Does the Terminal service license support such use wherein the data leaves the PC and gets pulled to a different PC?

Regards

Comment: Is it possible? Not sure - I think the API checks that you are connecting locally (and fails to connect otherwise). You would need to create a tunnel via ssh or something, but that would be a breach of the Bloomberg agreement - if you need data on a different machine than where the terminal is running, you will need to use DataLicence or SAPI depending on your needs.

Comment: int main() { SessionOptions sessionOptions; sessionOptions.setServerHost("10.10.10.10"); // Or specify machine name sessionOptions.setServerPort(8194); //Establish Session Session session(sessionOptions); //Attempt to Start Session if (!session.start()) { std::cerr <<"Failed to start session." << std::endl; return 1; }

Comment: This is the code given in an example on the documentation at https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/ in the Developer guide. This means they are supporting remote access.

Comment: Yes, that's if you are using SAPI or BPIPE - the authentication and data connection is done with the machine where the SAPI is running, not your local terminal - but you still need to be logged in on your terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not technically possible to connect to another PC which is running the Terminal and even if you can get around this it is not allowed by the license. Data downloaded on a PC running the Terminal must stay on that PC.

Bloomberg offers 2 solutions which don't require the Terminal to run and do require authentication: Server API (SAPI) and B-PIPE. To clarify, because you're describing having to run the Terminal on the PC you're necessarily talking about Desktop API.

Comment: Am I allowed to store the data collected using Server API?

Comment: I'd expect so - under certain conditions. Desktop API also allows this - on the PC that runs the Terminal. Also, see my edit.

Comment: If you need to store the data, you should probably consider Data Licence.